# php echo variable array

Tags: php, variables, echo

I try to replace a recursive echo with a variable.

Bu the result that I obtain is not the same

Here the working script:

```
if ( $currentpage <= 3 && $currentpage != "all" ) {
  $a = 3; 
  echo '<a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a-2) . '">' . ($a-2) . '</a>';
  echo '<a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a-1) . '">' . ($a-1) . '</a>';
  echo '<a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a) . '">' . ($a) . '</a>';  
  echo '<a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a+1) . '">' . ($a+1) . '</a>';
  echo '<a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a+2) . '">' . ($a+2) . '</a>';          
}  
if ( $currentpage > 3 && $currentpage != "all" && $currentpage < $pages-2) {
  $a = $currentpage;
  echo '<a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a-2) . '">' . ($a-2) . '</a>';
  echo '<a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a-1) . '">' . ($a-1) . '</a>';
  echo '<a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a) . '">' . ($a) . '</a>';  
  echo '<a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a+1) . '">' . ($a+1) . '</a>';
  echo '<a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a+2) . '">' . ($a+2) . '</a>'; 
}  
if ( $currentpage >= $pages-2 && $currentpage != "all" ) {
  $a = $pages-2; 
  echo '<a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a-2) . '">' . ($a-2) . '</a>';
  echo '<a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a-1) . '">' . ($a-1) . '</a>';
  echo '<a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a) . '">' . ($a) . '</a>';  
  echo '<a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a+1) . '">' . ($a+1) . '</a>';
  echo '<a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a+2) . '">' . ($a+2) . '</a>';          
}
```

And my try without success (no error but not the same results):

```
$pagenb =  '<a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a-2) . '">' . ($a-2) . '</a>
            <a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a-1) . '">' . ($a-1) . '</a>
            <a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a) . '">' . ($a) . '</a>  
            <a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a+1) . '">' . ($a+1) . '</a>
            <a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a+2) . '">' . ($a+2) . '</a>';

if ( $currentpage <= 3 && $currentpage != "all" ) {
  $a = 3; 
  echo $pagenb;          
}  
if ( $currentpage > 3 && $currentpage != "all" && $currentpage < $pages-2) {
  $a = $currentpage;
  echo $pagenb; 
}  
if ( $currentpage >= $pages-2 && $currentpage != "all" ) {
  $a = $pages-2; 
  echo $pagenb;          
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP has no lazy evaluation per se (except eval()'ing it only then...)

But you could write it into a function you call with `$a` as function parameter:

```
function pagenb ($a) {
    return  '<a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a-2) . '">' . ($a-2) . '</a>
             <a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a-1) . '">' . ($a-1) . '</a>
             <a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a) . '">' . ($a) . '</a>  
             <a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a+1) . '">' . ($a+1) . '</a>
             <a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a+2) . '">' . ($a+2) . '</a>';
}

if ( $currentpage <= 3 && $currentpage != "all" ) {
        echo pagenb(3);          
    }  
    if ( $currentpage > 3 && $currentpage != "all" && $currentpage < $pages-2) {
        echo pagenb($currentpage); 
    }  
    if ( $currentpage >= $pages-2 && $currentpage != "all" ) {
        echo pagenb($pages-2);          
    }
```

Comment: Do you think if it's possible to add an if condition like this : if $currentpage = ($a-2) or ($a-1) or $a... then change bgcolors2 in the class by bgcolor1.

Comment: It is, add a second parameter for the color?

Comment: yes. This code is for a pagination. I want to highlight the current page. I display each time 5 pages. For the 5 lines in pagenb if the line with the addition (for example ($a-1) = $currentpage) correspond to the current page then I change the bgcolor (so it must be in a variable I think)

Answer (score 3):

Try and move the code around a bit:

```
        if ( $currentpage <= 3 && $currentpage != "all" ) {
            $a = 3; 
        }  
        if ( $currentpage > 3 && $currentpage != "all" && $currentpage < $pages-2) {
            $a = $currentpage;
        }  
        if ( $currentpage >= $pages-2 && $currentpage != "all" ) {
            $a = $pages-2; 
        }

$pagenb =  '<a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a-2) . '">' . ($a-2) . '</a>
                   <a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a-1) . '">' . ($a-1) . '</a>
                   <a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a) . '">' . ($a) . '</a>  
                   <a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a+1) . '">' . ($a+1) . '</a>
                   <a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a+2) . '">' . ($a+2) . '</a>';

            echo $pagenb;          
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using an anonymous function assigned to a variable:

```
<?php

$pages = 10;
$currentpage = 8;
$pagination = function($value) {
    for ($a = $value, $p = -2; $p <= 2; $p++) {
        echo '<a class="page bgcolor2" href="?pagenb=' . ($a+$p) . '">' . ($a+$p) . '</a>';
    }
};

if ($currentpage != 'all') {
    if ($currentpage <= 3) {
        $pagination(3);
    } elseif ($currentpage > 3 && $currentpage < $pages-2) {
        $pagination($currentpage);
    } elseif ($currentpage >= $pages-2) {
        $pagination($pages-2);
    }
}
```